# Printing a PublicKey in C++

Tags: stellar-core

I've tried to print via:

```
void printQuorumSet ( SCPQuorumSet set )
{
    for (auto validator: set.validators)
        std::cout << validator << ' ';
}
```

But that gives me:

```
scp/test/QuorumSetTests.cpp:20:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream'
  (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'stellar::PublicKey')
```

I don't see any `toString` / `pretty` / `format` code that can help me print out the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like I found the answer: `KeyUtils::toStrKey(pk)`